# How to merge 3 subdomains into main domain in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How to merge 3 subdomains into main domain in cakephp.
I have 1 domain abc.com , and 3 sub-domain ,subdomain1.abc.com, subdomain2.abc.com , subdomain3.abc.com. I am using cakephp 3.0 .All 4 (domain and subdomain) have different different database, url and data flow with respect to its url.

Comment: like 
abc.com/home
subdomain1.abc.com/home
subdomain2.abc.com/home
subdomain3.abc.com/home

i want to merge these into 1 url with sub-directory (main,subdomain1,subdomain2,subdomain3)like below, how to achieve this.
abc.com 
abc.com/subdomain1
abc.com/subdomain2
abc.com/subdomain3

abc.com/home 
abc.com/subdomain1/home
abc.com/subdomain2/home
abc.com/subdomain3/home 

and so on

Comment: hi, Abhinav kher, welcome to StackOverflow. it will be a great help if you also add what you have tries to reach the same goal and why do you want to do it?